# How can I sort and de-dupe a very long list of words?

Tags: linux, windows, sorting, awk

I have a 400 megabyte file.  The file is a list of words, each word on a single line.  End of lines are a mix of cr/lf and lf.  Some of the words are unicode.

I'd prefer answers for Linux or Windows please.  I'm happy to install software, but I'd prefer open source.

I need to remove all the words that are less than 8 characters.  I then need to de-duplicate the list.  (Sorting the list is nice, but not need unless it's part of the process.)  I don't care about the unicode words - they can stay or go.  Stripping them out is fine.

To remove all the words that are 7 characters or less I use awk:

```
awk "length($0) > 7" wordlist.txt > mynewwordlist.txt
```

(This is Windows, sorry for the " instead of ')

I then try to use sort, because I can then use awk again to de-dupe lines.  Sort didn't like the wordlist.  I think (but I'm not sure) that the unicode broke it.

So, how do I de-dupe the wordlist?  Or how do I sort the wordlist so that I can use awk to de-dupe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To dedupe, you need to `sort -u` – it will only output unique lines. This is an option specified by POSIX, so you'll probably find it on any system.

```
sort -u wordlist.txt | awk 'length($0) > 7'
```

Use double quotes for `awk` if you're on Windows. Note that the sorting step is not optional, as `uniq` requires duplicate lines to be adjacent in order to remove them.

If you have Unicode problems, this could be a problem of your locale. You can set `LC_ALL=C` to force the native byte value comparison – the actual sorting order doesn't matter for you anyway. Or, you could use `iconv` to convert  the file from Unicode to another encoding if that's the issue.

Comment: sort has a `-u` ( `--unique` ) option, at least on cygwin.

Comment: You're right, I thought it wasn't POSIX, will correct my post!

Answer (score 3):

In case someone needs to do this without having access to `awk`, you can also use `grep` for selecting words of at least a given length:

```
sort -u   wordlist.txt | grep '........'
```

Comment: Cool hack.  I wouldn't have thought of doing something like that.